# Reading and Writing line by line from/to the same file

Tags: perl

I'm working with xml-files which I need to manipulate in my script. My first approach on this was:

```
qx(perl export_xml.pl $export_params >  $path$prefix\investment.xml); # Create the xml-file


open DERI, '+<'.$path.$prefix.'investment.xml' or die 'Can\'t open investment.xml: '.$!;    
my @derivative_xml = <DERI>;
seek(DERI, 0, 0);

foreach (@derivative_xml) {
    $_ =~ s/^\s*$//g;
    $_ =~ s/^.*detected on Server.*$//g;
    $_ = encode('utf8', $_);
} 

print DERI join('', @derivative_xml);
```

This is working for testing purposes, but unfortunately the real files are just too big for that (up to 6GB).

Is there a way to read the file line by line and then modify the input through the filehandle? Something like

```
foreach (<DERI>) { #@derivative_xml) {
    $_ =~ s/^\s*$//g;
    $_ =~ s/^.*detected on Server.*$//g;
    $_ = encode('utf8', $_);
}
```

I can't really test that in a non-ridiculous amount of time, so it would be pretty nice, if I didn't have to trial and error here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, tell why you should change your xml-file? Really, may be it will be better to create modified file? "ouput" file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. No need of another script file.

```
perl -pi -e 's/^\s*$//g;s/^.*detected on Server.*$//g;$_ = encode('utf8', $_)' investment.xml
```

Did not test though with huge file upto 6GB. Test this and check how much time it takes.

Comment: Okay thanks.
I'm gonna run the script overnight and will update you tomorrow :)

Comment: How much time it took BTW?